# HTML/CSS Alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the code:

```css
/* Text */

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  /* color: transparent; */
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}


/*Vertical Flip*/

.verticalFlip {
  display: inline;
}

.verticalFlip span {
  animation: vertical 5s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: vertical 3.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 5s linear infinite 0s;
  /* color: transparent; */
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  opacity: 0;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Word
    <div class="verticalFlip"><span>  Change</span><span> Text</span></div>
  </h1>
  </section
```

Why is the word `Text` outputting spaces after? Why is the alignment off?

The issue is happening because I removed `position: absolute;` from `.verticalFlip span` but adding the property also makes the alignment off where some parts of the word seems to be cutting. I am trying to make `.verticalFlip span` the same as `#hero h1`. How can I make it like that? Any suggestions please?

Comment: For myself, I am not seeing the word "Text" at all

Comment: hmm on my end, I can see it fine

Comment: Why are you not able to see it

Comment: Safari does not show the word "Text"

Comment: Ah try using chrome. I'm using chrome

Answer (score 1):

Your description of what you want is rather vague, but if you want both words/spans alternating at the same position, add `position: absolute;` and optionally some `margin-left` to the `.verticalFlip span` rule.

To make sure this works in any context, also add `position: relative;` to the parent element of those two spans (i.e. the `.verticalFlip` div) to define it as the reference for the absolute position.

```css
/* Text */

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  /* color: transparent; */
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}


/*Vertical Flip*/

.verticalFlip {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.verticalFlip span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  animation: vertical 5s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: vertical 3.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 5s linear infinite 0s;
  /* color: transparent; */
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  opacity: 0;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Word
    <div class="verticalFlip"><span>  Change</span><span> Text</span></div>
  </h1>
  </section
```